# Transparent spectrogram selection overlays

Tags: c++, transparency, vcl

I'm trying to create transparent selection overlays on top of a spectrogram but it doesn't quite work. I mean the result is not really satisfactory. In contrast, the overlays painted on top of a waveform work well but I need to support both the waveform as well as the spectrogram view (and maybe other views in the future)

The selection overlay works fine in the waveform view

[image]

Here's the selection overlay in the spectrogram view (the selection looks really bad and obscures parts of the spectrogram)

[image]

The code (VCL) is the same for both views

```
void TWaveDisplayContainer::DrawSelectedRegion(){


        if(selRange.selStart.x == selRange.selEnd.x){
            DrawCursorPosition( selRange.selStart.x);
            return;
        }
        Graphics::TBitmap *pWaveBmp = eContainerView == WAVEFORM ? pWaveBmpLeft : pSfftBmpLeft;
        TRect selRect(selRange.selStart.x, 0, selRange.selEnd.x, pWaveLeft->Height);
        TCanvas *pCanvas = pWaveLeft->Canvas;
        int copyMode = pCanvas->CopyMode;

        pCanvas->Draw(0,0, pWaveBmp);
        pCanvas->Brush->Color = clActiveBorder;
        pCanvas->CopyMode = cmSrcAnd;
        pCanvas->Rectangle(selRect);
        pCanvas->CopyRect(selRect, pWaveBmp->Canvas, selRect);
        pCanvas->CopyMode = copyMode;

        if(numChannels == 2){

            TCanvas* pOtherCanvas = pWaveRight->Canvas;
            pWaveBmp = eContainerView == WAVEFORM ? pWaveBmpRight : 
 pSfftBmpRight;
            pOtherCanvas->Draw(0,0, pWaveBmp);
            pOtherCanvas->Brush->Color = clActiveBorder;
            pOtherCanvas->CopyMode = cmSrcAnd;
            pOtherCanvas->Rectangle(selRect);
            pOtherCanvas->CopyRect(selRect, pWaveBmp->Canvas, selRect);
            pOtherCanvas->CopyMode = copyMode;

        }
}
```

So, I'm using `cmSrcAnd` copy mode and the `CopyRect` method to do the actual painting/drawing (`TCanvas` corresponds to a device context (`HDC on Windows`). I think, since a spectrogram, unlike a waveform, doesn't really have a single background colour using simple mixing copy modes isn't going to work well in most cases.

Note that I can still accomplish what I want but that would require messing with the individual pixels, which is something I'd like to avoid if possible)

I'm basically looking for an `API` (`VCL` wraps `GDI` so even WINAPI is fine) able to do this.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: I think that this question is similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702868/how-do-you-do-both-blending-and-transparency-using-just-pure-vcl-on-bitmapped-im
 You may want to look at the comments bellow it - the Graphics32 library looks quite promising. In particular take a look at the "CombineMode": https://graphics32.github.io/Docs/Units/GR32/Classes/TCustomBitmap32/Properties/CombineMode.htm

Comment: Thanks, that library looks interesting and is rather comprehensive. I'll look into it even if I decide to write my own transparent overlay routine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question and hopefully this will prove to be useful to some people. Since there's apparently no way this can be achieved
in either plain `VCL` or using `WINAPI` (except in some situations), I've written a simple function that blends a bitmap (`32bpp / 24bpp`) with an overlay colour (any colour). 
The actual result will also depend on the weights (`w0,w1`) given to the `red, green and blue` components of an individual pixel. Changing these will produce
an overlay that leans more toward the spectrogram colour or the overlay colour respectively.

**The code**

```
Graphics::TBitmap *TSelectionOverlay::GetSelectionOverlay(Graphics::TBitmap *pBmp, TColor selColour,
TRect &rect, EChannel eChannel){

 Graphics::TBitmap *pSelOverlay = eChannel==LEFT ? pSelOverlayLeft : pSelOverlayRight;

 const unsigned cGreenShift = 8;
 const unsigned cBlueShift = 16;

 const unsigned overlayWidth = abs(rect.right-rect.left);
 const unsigned overlayHeight = abs(rect.bottom-rect.top);

 pSelOverlay->Width = pBmp->Width;
 pSelOverlay->Height = pBmp->Height;

 const unsigned startOffset = rect.right>rect.left ? rect.left : rect.right;

 pSelOverlay->Assign(pBmp);

 unsigned char cRed0, cGreen0, cBlue0,cRed1, cGreen1, cBlue1, bRedColor0, bGreenColor0, bBlueColor0;

 cBlue0 =   selColour >> cBlueShift;
 cGreen0 =  selColour >> cGreenShift & 0xFF;
 cRed0 =    selColour & 0xFF;

 unsigned *pPixel;

 for(int i=0;i<overlayHeight;i++){

    pPixel = (unsigned*)pSelOverlay->ScanLine[i];//provides access to the pixel array
    for(int j=0;j<overlayWidth;j++){

    unsigned pixel =  pPixel[startOffset+j];
    cBlue1 =    pixel >> cBlueShift;
    cGreen1 =   pixel >> cGreenShift & 0xFF;
    cRed1 =     pixel & 0xFF;

    //blend the current bitmap pixel with the overlay colour

    const float w0 = 0.5f; //these weights influence the appearance of the overlay (here we use 50%)
    const float w1 = 0.5f;

    bRedColor0 = cRed0*w0+cRed1*w1;
    bGreenColor0 = cGreen0*w0+cGreen1*w1);
    bBlueColor0 = cBlue0*w0+cBlue1*w1;

    pPixel[startOffset+j] =  ((bBlueColor0 << cBlueShift) | (bGreenColor0 << cGreenShift)) | bRedColor0;
    }
 }

  return pSelOverlay;
}
```

Note that for some reason, `CopyRect` used with a `CopyMode` value of `cmSrcCopy` didn't work well so I used `Draw` instead.

```
pCanvas->CopyMode = cmSrcCopy;
pCanvas->CopyRect(dstRect, pSelOverlay->Canvas, srcRec);//this still didn't work well--possibly a bug
```

so I used

```
pCanvas->Draw(0,0, pSelOverlay);
```

**The result**

[image]